# Can you create a Google map in a virtual element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wondering it is possible to create a working Google map in a virtual element which can then be pasted into any page at any time.

So here is my JS when targeting an element which already exists on the page.

```
var mapLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5174456, -0.1305081);
var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5170951, -0.1367416);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: mapLatLong,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_canvas'), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">BrocklebankPenn</h1>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                            '<p>5th floor, 58-60 Berners Street,<br />London,<br />W1T 3NQ,<br />United Kingdom</p>'+
                            '<p>+44 (0)20 3137 7034</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'BrocklebankPenn'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

infowindow.open(map,marker);
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
this.mapCanvas = document.createElement('div');
this.mapCanvas.setAttribute('id', 'map_canvas');

var mapLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5174456, -0.1305081);
var markerLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5170951, -0.1367416);

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: mapLatLong,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

var map = new google.maps.Map($(this.mapCanvas), mapOptions);

var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">BrocklebankPenn</h1>'+
                        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
                            '<p>5th floor, 58-60 Berners Street,<br />London,<br />W1T 3NQ,<br />United Kingdom</p>'+
                            '<p>+44 (0)20 3137 7034</p>'+
                        '</div>'+
                    '</div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'BrocklebankPenn'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

infowindow.open(map,marker);

this.$el.html(this.mapCanvas);
```

Basically the exact same thing but with a `variable` instead of `#map_canvas`, I have taken this approach with JS in the past but it does not seem to be working for Google maps, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'position' of undefined
```

Which I am not sure of.

If anyone can help that would be awesome.

Cheers,
Luke.

Comment: I think the problem is you seem to be trying to use the 'map_canvas' div in the google maps JS before you've inserted it into the page.  I'd say do `this.$el.html(this.mapCanvas);` before calling your initialize function which should wrap up everything else from `var mapLatLong` down

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to do, I want to set up the map before inserting to the DOM, but I am getting the feeling it is not possible.

Comment: Yeah I don't think so.  What about having a normal div present in the DOM from the start, but hidden initially, then only showing it after you've created the map?

Comment: It's a great idea, but unfortunately won't work with my setup, I have and single page app and every new page is loaded through AJAX and then slid in like a carousel. So there is nowhere to place to div on page load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's possible, Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/5SjnK/

The issues with your code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($(this.mapCanvas), mapOptions);
```

`$(this.mapCanvas)` is a jQuery-object, but it's expected to be an HTML-Element

```
this.$el.html(this.mapCanvas);
```

Don't set the html, you must insert the original node into the document.

But I wouldn't suggest it, there will be more issues, e.g. when you use API-methods that try to access the parentNode of the map-div or methods that need to calculate positions inside the document(both will fail before the node has been inserted into the document).

Related to ***pasted into any page***:

It's not possible, the document where you use the map must be the same document where you load the API, the API internally uses references to the window/document where the API has been loaded. See this question: [Marker drag not working in iframe under Chrome and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426835/marker-drag-not-working-in-iframe-under-chrome-and-firefox/23438995?noredirect=1#comment36149474_23438995)

But as long as ***any page*** doesn't mean "any document"(regarding to your description it's always the same document) it's possible.

Comment: Nice solution thanks! Oh and to answer your question, it is all 1 document and each page is loaded into the same document.